# Is there any module for ejabberd like MongooseIm mod_inbox?

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, mongoose-im

PLEASE! I've been trying to find some inbox module for ejabberd like MongooseIm's but without success

I would like to know if there are any, and if not, can I adapt MongooseIm's **mod_inbox** in ejabberd or is it better to switch to MongooseIm?

EDITED:
or how can I create a similar implementation on the client with 0313 - MAM and 0013 - Offline messages that give me the same or approximate result. Please help, I'm breaking my head, I don't want to change the ejabberd but if necessary, no problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm on MongooseIM core team.

---

It's not clear how much you've invested in deploying and integrating ejabberd. If the integration is only on XMPP level, then MongooseIM is mostly a drop-in replacement. You can just [grab a MongooseIM container](https://hub.docker.com/r/mongooseim/mongooseim) or [a prebuilt package](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/resources/download.html) and be done with it.

If you have, on the other hand, invested in metrics gathering, deployment pipelines, infrastructure as code, etc, then switching might cost you a bit more effort due to some differences in how the projects are built from source, report stats, format logs. The switch is still relatively easy, but there's some overhead involved.

If you're comfortable programming in Erlang, then porting `mod_inbox` won't be a big problem (it's a matter of a few days at most). If you don't have Erlang experience and hiring is not an option, then better stick to prebuilt MongooseIM container images / packages.

Comment: My infrastructure is not only XMPP, I am integrating with Python in the backend the chat connected to the frontend but the authentication in the chat is external (via oauth)

Comment: I want to end this problem now, what would you advise me (excluding the fact that you are on the Mongoose team), adapt mod_inbox to ejabberd, or switch to mongooseim? keep in mind that I will customize the delivery of the messages for one2one and groupchat

Comment: If you're going to customise message delivery, then I believe MongooseIM has a better test suite which would allow you to define acceptance criteria and test the changes against them. This is really way more convenient than finding bugs in production and going back to the implementation with obscure error reports. Integration-wise, both servers offer good capabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your help, maybe i will move to MongooseIM, i saw the source code and think it's more clear and robust, because a lot of code in ejabberd do not implement specs

Comment: @erszcz Hi~ mind if i hijack a little to ask about mongooseim?

Comment: @cYee No problem, how can I help?

Comment: @erszcz Thanksss! Actually I am in the midst of transitioning from ejabberd to mongoose but encountering a crash for handover session... whenever user reconnects. But system still functioning, just that user will reauth again, whenever it reconnects, Just wondering, is it a false alert?

Comment: @cYee For this kind of problem your best bet is to create a new ticket with the crash details at https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/issues/new - that will help us fix the problem for the benefit of all MongooseIM users.

Comment: @erszcz I saw someone posted it here. https://github.com/esl/MongooseIM/issues/2933 but doesnt seem that everyone is having that issue, probably is my config so just try my luck with StackOverflow.